How is FHIR store searched by Practitioner for all PractitionerRoles (GET, POST, .search not working)?
A Practitioner can be included in more than one PractitionerRole resources.  I'm attempting here to retrieve all the PractitionerRole Resources for a particular Practitioner.  This works in the Google FHIR Store Viewer, but the same http request fails in code.  Here are 3 examples: .search, POST, and GET
Note that this search string **works ** in the Google Healthcare FHIR viewer , also note that there is no _search in this... (?) It's specifying a practitioner to get all PractitionerRole that include the practitioner
this works ok in google's fhir viewer:   https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/combine-fhir-smart-store/locations/us-central1/datasets/COMBINE-FHIR-v1/fhirStores/1/fhir/PractitionerRole?practitioner=30904792-995a-4551-b185-657d8e4ea08e
So therefor a GET request should work...
(all the path variables are set correctly)
    const practitionerId = '30904792-995a-4551-b185-657d8e4ea08e';
    const searchUrl = `https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/${LOCATION}/datasets/${DATASET_ID}/fhirStores/${FHIR_STORE_ID}/fhir/PractitionerRole?practitioner=${practitionerId}`;

    const client = await auth.getClient();
    const response = await client.request({
      url: searchUrl,   // The URL with query parameters
      method: 'GET',    // Use GET method for search with query parameters
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/fhir+json',  // Request FHIR in JSON format
      }
    });

the response has no data :
https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/combine-fhir-smart-store/locations/us-centr[…]erRole?practitioner=30904792-995a-4551-b185-657d8e4ea08e
{"config":{"url":"https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/combine-fhir-smart-store/locations/us-central1/datasets/COMBINE-FHIR-v1/fhirStores/1/fhir/PractitionerRole?practitioner=30904792-995a-4551-b185-657d8e4ea08e","method":"GET","headers":{"Accept":"application/fhir+json","Authorization":"Bearer --","User-Agent":"google-api-nodejs-client/9.14.1","x-goog-api-client":"gl-node/20.14.0"},"responseType":"unknown"},"data":{},"headers":{"alt-svc":"h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000","content-length":"2455","content-type":"application/fhir+json;charset=utf-8","date":"Mon, 09 Sep 2024 01:08:23 GMT","server":"ESF","vary":"Origin, X-Origin, Referer","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-xss-protection":"0"},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","request":{"responseURL":"https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/combine-fhir-smart-store/locations/us-central1/datasets/COMBINE-FHIR-v1/fhirStores/1/fhir/PractitionerRole?practitioner=30904792-995a-4551-b185-657d8e4ea08e"}}
something else must be wrong...

Actually the routine does return data, but JSON.stringify doesn't show it.  Use handleBlobResponse to get access to the data.
async function handleBlobResponse(responseData) {
  //console.log("in handleBlob");
  //console.log('handleBlob- response type:', typeof responseData);

  if (responseData && responseData[Symbol.toStringTag] === 'Blob') {
   // console.log("it's a blob");
    const buffer = await responseData.arrayBuffer();
    const text = Buffer.from(buffer).toString('utf-8');
    const ret = JSON.parse(text);
    //console.log("ret:", JSON.stringify(ret));
    return ret;
  } else if (typeof responseData === 'object' && responseData !== null) {
    // If it's already an object (but not null), return it as is
    return responseData;
  } else {
    console.error('handleBlob- Unexpected response type:', typeof responseData);
    throw new Error('handle-Blob Unexpected response type');
  }
}

